# Show that for each integer $n\geq 2$. there is exactly one bipartite graph order $n$ size $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor$

Tags: graph-theory

Show that for each integer $n\geq 2$. there is exactly one bipartite graph order $n$ size $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor$

I know that there is no bipartite order $n$ can have size bigger than $\lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor$. But I'm not sure I know how to use this fact to prove this theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: If $n$ is even, then the complete bipartite graph that arises from distributing the vertices equally between the partite sets has size
$$
\frac{n}{2}\cdot\frac{n}{2}=\frac{n^2}{4}=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor.
$$

If $n$ is odd, then the complete bipartite graph that arises from distributing the vertices as equally as possible between the partite sets has size
$$
\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{n^2-1}{4}=\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\right\rfloor.
$$

HINT 2: Given the vertex distribution above, suppose we move $k$ vertices from one partite set to the other. What is the size of the resulting complete bipartite graph then? Can it ever equal $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see how this show there exactly one bipartite graph of that size. Can you explain it a little bit further please.

Comment: What happens to the size of the complete bipartite graph if you deviate from these vertex distributions? Is there some way to distribute the vertices other than we have prescribed and still yield a bipartite graph of size $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$? If the answer is "yes", then there cannot be a unique graph of size $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$. If the answer is "no", then the graph described above must be the unique bipartite graph of size $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$.